# Massive live video streaming using Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, glx

I am considering different ways to stream a massive number of live videos to the screen in linux/X11, using multiple independent processes.

I started the project initially with openGL/GLX and openGL textures, but that was a dead end.  The reason: "context switching". It turns out that (especially nvidia) performs poorly when several (independent multi-)processes are manipulating at fast pace textures, using multiple contexts.  This results in crashes, freezes, etc.

( see the following thread: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/nouveau/2017-February/027286.html )

I finally turned into Xvideo and it seems to work very nicely.  My initial tests show that Xvideo handles video dumping ~ 10 times more effectively than openGL and does not crash.  One can demonstrate this running ~ 10 vlc clients with 720p@25fps and trying both Xvideo and OpenGL output (remember to put all fullscreen).

However, I am suspecting that Xvideo uses, under the hood, openGL, so let's see if I am getting this right ..

Both Xvideo and GLX are extension modules of X11, but:

(A) Dumping video through Xvideo:

- XVideo considers the whole screen as a device port and manipulates it directly (it has these god-like powers, being an extension to X11)
- .. so it only needs a *single* context from the graphics driver.  Lets call it context 1.
- Process 1 requests Xvideo services for a certain window .. Xvideo manages it into a certain portion of the screen, using context 1.
- Process 2 requests Xvideo services for a certain window .. Xvideo manages it into a certain portion of the screen, using context 1.

(B) Dumping video "manually" through GLX and openGL texture dumping:

- Process 1 requests a context from glx, gets context 1 and starts dumping textures with it.
- Process 2 requests a context from glx, gets context 2 and starts dumping textures with it.

Am I getting this right?

Is there any way to achieve, using openGL directly, situation (A) ?
.. one might have to drop GLX completely, which starts to be a bit hard-core.

Comment: You're wrong in assuming that XVideo under the hood was using OpenGL. XVideo is an independent extension to the X11 protocol and can be supported perfectly by GPUs that lack 3D rasterization support. However for the sake of efficiency you should probably use VDPAU instead of XVideo. Also what's stopping your from using a single OpenGL context in a single process? You can perfectly well decode in separate processed (say using ffmpeg), and pass the decoded data through pipes into a display process.

Comment: Regarding to vdpau, it is now supported in opensource drivers by mesa, but they seem to be still a bit green.  Nvidia proprietary driver's vdpaus have all kind of artificial restrictions from number of allowed simultaneous vdpau decoders to allowed h264 profiles (they wan't to sell you their uber-expensive gfx cards) - wouldn't recommend proprietary nvidia vdpau even to my worst enemy!  .. you'll never know how many vdpau threads you can decode and with what h264 profile/level.

Comment: Regarding to using a single "master" process for openGL texture dumping.. I was thinking of this possibility as well, but by using shared memory.  Sending decoded bitmaps, 720p@25 fps from several sources by pipes .. aren't pipes handled by the kernel?  Would they have enough capacity for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I finally got it sorted out, using OpenGL textures and multithreading.  This seems to be the optimal way:

https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-core/html/process_chart.html

(disclaimer: I did that)